# Does LoadRunner measure UI response time?

Tags: loadrunner

I know LoadRunner is used for system responses but I wonder whether it measures also e.g. rendering time (thousands of items in large lists etc.). I guess it could be done just by verifying that particular object appeared in the UI but then, I think LoadRunner does not run browsers and only sends recorded data. I would be very greateful for any input.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LoadRunner has many ways to measure rendering time.   Starting at the top of the stack and going down

- Citrix/RDP Virtual User.   Sync is on bitmap with this type so the bitmap has to be fully rendered to the client
- GUI Virtual User.   This has been part of LoadRunner since version 1.   First it was XRunner, then it became WinRunner and in the Current product it is QuickTest Professional.   GUI Virtual Users were quite popular in the thick client server era and now that the web clients are getting thicker and richer it is making a return.  Generally you are only going to run a handful of these while the remainder are transport level users
- TruClient (LoadRunner 11 on).  Runs the full firefox stack, including rendering.

As you move up the stack to run a full client there are tradeoffs.   The first is that the resource cost per virtual user becomes larger as you have to run the full client instead of just reproducing the conversational behavior to the server.   If you have a browser that is 500MB plus your sampling add ins you can see that even on a 4GB host with shared execution code you are still not going to achieve a whole lot of users per host.    If you look at QTP based GUI Virtual Users then you are looking at a sinngle virtual user per OS instance.

Your statement, " I think LoadRunner does not run browsers and only sends recorded data" when you look at both the full firefox stack in the TruClient user type as well as the ability to run GUI Virtual Users operating against whatever browser you choose pretty much causes this statement to be set aside.

Now the next big question.   Assuming that it is not your code and it is the rendering of the browswer which is slow, what will you be able to do to change this behavior to make your app run faster?   Can you change IE?   Do you have the time, skills, budget to start digging into the source for Firefox or Chrome to find the slow code and update it?

Comment: This is not about browsers being slow but about our app being slow..We have LoadRunner 9, so TruClient is out of consideration but thanks, I did not know about it. BTW, I can see TruClient supports only Javascript based apps (or regular web pages+javascript based ones? What about flex then..)

Comment: If you are trying to measure flex/flash/acrobat/... or any other in browser add in for processing and rendering then you are looking at a GUI Virtual user.   LoadRunner can produce load for all of these types of extra layer add ins at the transport layer, but as you "seem" to need GUI rendering, then you need a GUI virtual user.    One should note, if it is slow for one user for rendering, then it is best to attack this in functional testing and not wait until later with performance testing.   What is slow for one will never be fast for many

Comment: Thank you. Looks like you are the only expert on LR on stackoverflow. Also from what I read, only one GUI Vuser / per workstation (unless virtual desktops are used).

Comment: @JamesPulley, Regarding licensing, do you know if the new 1day-vuser-license ([$2 per](https://www.pronq.com/buy/loadrunner)) include GUI vusers?

Comment: Please refer to your VAR for licensing costs.